# Open a new page when I click on a JSF table

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I have this `h:outputLink' which I use to open a new page when I click on a JSF table row:

```
<h:outputLink id="lnkHidden" value="page.html"  style="text-decoration:none; color:white;">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{item.value}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

I use this JavaScript to open a new page when I click on a row:

```
// For clicking on a row and opening new page
function addOnclickToDatatableRows() {
    //gets all the generated rows in the html table
    var trs = document.getElementById('form:dataTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
    .getElementsByTagName('tr');
    //on every row, add onclick function (this is what you're looking for)
    for (var i = 0; trs.length > i; i++) {
        var cells = trs[i].cells;                    
        for(var j=1; j < cells.length; j++){
            cells[j].onclick = new Function("rowOnclick(this.parentElement)");
        }                    
    }
}

function rowOnclick(tr) {
    var elements = tr.cells[0].childNodes;
    for(var i = 0; elements.length > i; i++) {                           
        if ((typeof elements[i].id != "undefined") && (elements[i].id.indexOf("lnkHidden") > -1)) {
            location.href=elements[i].href;
            break;
        }
    }                
    return false;
}
```

I updated the code this way:

```
<h:commandLink id="lnkHidden" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;"
               actionListener="#{bean.pageRedirect}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.sessionValue}" value="#{item.value}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

managed bean:

```
public void setSessionValue(Object value)
    {

       ...........

    }

public String pageRedirect()
    {

        return "/DatacenterProfile.html";
    }
```

It turns out that the JavaScript is nit working properly because I changed to `h:commandLink`. Can you help me to fix this problem?

***P.S***

I tested to use `h:commandButton`

```
<h:commandButton id="lnkHidden" style="text-decoration:none; color:white; display:none"
               action="#{bean.pageRedirect}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.sessionValue}" value="#{item.value}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

When I click on a table wor I'm always redirected to page

```
http://<ip>:8080/app/undefined
```

I suppose that the problem is into the JavaScript code. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: If you want to open the link in a new page, just use the `target="_blank"` in your `<h:form>`.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I got your problem right. But if you are trying to redirect on click of the `commandLink`, I think your problem is, that you can not redirect using the `actionListener` property, instead you should use the `action` property, otherwise the return value of `pageRedirect` would have no effect.

Look at [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/commandLink.html) for further explanation.

Comment: What does your table look like? Is there a `commandButton` in each row? Are you trying to redirect to the location of the commandButton on click of the entire table row or what are you trying to do? From what you have posted it looks like you are just trying to redirect on a static URL on click of a commandButton. I dont really get what you are intended to do with the JS, as you are asking for the commandButton. Could you please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

You should debug your javascript, try to display the value of **href** to see if it is what you want:

```
function rowOnclick(tr) {
    var elements = tr.cells[0].childNodes;
    for(var i = 0; elements.length > i; i++) {                           
        if ((typeof elements[i].id != "undefined") && (elements[i].id.indexOf("lnkHidden") > -1)) {

            alert(elements[i].href);

            location.href=elements[i].href;
            break;
        }
    }                
    return false;
}
```

Regards,